# Excel Multiple IF Blank statements handling

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am grabbing data from 1 cell, then another and adding them together in a new cell but I need to add `;` as a separator but cannot work out if conditions, here is what I'm trying to do

CURRENT CODE:

```
=P1&";"&R1
```

Required:

- If P1 is empty and R1 is empty to be blank in new cell
- If P1 is empty and R1 is not empty to just show R1 value in a new cell without ;
- If P1 and R1 have values to join them but separate with ;

So would look like;

> VALUE1;VALUE2 (if has both)
>
> VALUE2 (if just second cell)
>
> VALUE1 (if just first cell)
>
> Blank if both cells empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
=if(and(len(p1), len(r1)), p1&";"&r1, p1&r1)
```

Comment: Can i be a pain? just noticed need to add another cell.... so far got to this but of course not working lol =IF(AND(LEN(P1), LEN(R1), LEN(U1)), P1&";"&R1&";"&U1, P1&R1&U1)